# Wait until a message has been received and pass the message body using C# RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, multithreading, rabbitmq

I want to read a message from a queue, and once available wants to send the byte[] outside the consumer class.

```
public byte[] Receive()
{
    if (messagingAdapter == null)
        return default(byte[]);

    byte[] messageBody = null;
    var channel = messagingAdapter.GetChannel();
    channel.BasicQos(prefetchSize: 0, prefetchCount: 1, global: false);
    using (var subscription = new Subscription(channel, containerName, false))
    {
        while (channel.IsOpen)
        {
            var success = subscription.Next(5000, out BasicDeliverEventArgs eventArgs);
            if (success == false) continue;
            messageBody = eventArgs.Body;
            channel.BasicAck(eventArgs.DeliveryTag, false);
        }
    }
    return messageBody;
}
```

In the above code, there are two issues (can be more).

1) Even after writing prefetchCount = 1, it still reads all the messages.
2) Ever after waiting for 5 seconds, I never get a success and I'm not able to send the body to outside.

I have written one more code, which does the same thing but in the post itself, it was written that it is not recommended way of doing.

Sample Code:

```
using (var signal = new ManualResetEvent(false))
{
    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

    consumer.Received +=

    (sender, args) =>
    {
        messageBody = args.Body;
        signal.Set();
    };
    //// start consuming
    channel.BasicConsume(containerName, true, consumer);
    // wait until message is received or timeout reached
    bool timeout = !signal.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    // cancel subscription
    channel.BasicCancel(consumer.ConsumerTag);
    if (timeout)
    {
        // timeout reached - do what you need in this case
        throw new Exception("timeout");
    }
    return messageBody;
    // at this point messageBody is received
}
```

Comment: It looks if there any quite a number of messages than it takes time to respond. So the issue is with BasicQos settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading with `channel.BasicGet` instead, something like this:

```
private byte[] ReadRabbitMsg(IModel channel, string queue)
{
    if (channel.MessageCount(queue) == 0) return null;
    BasicGetResult result = channel.BasicGet(queue, true);
    if (result == null) return null;
    else
    {
        IBasicProperties props = result.BasicProperties;
        byte[] buff = result.Body;
    }
}
```

Comment: This I have already done, But want to use Subscription to achieve the same.

Comment: Well, i must have misunderstood the question then. Your two problems seemed to be that you were unable to process messages 1-by-1 and that the processing never exits? It has been awhile since i did performance testing on this, but 1-by-1 reading was actually rather fast, for my needs anyway.